# exceptions to same-origin policy

Tags: javascript, exception, dom, same-origin-policy

I know the same origin rule. I wonder if there is an exception such that a parent document script can read or write a child (iframe) document content but the latter cannot do it for the former, or viceversa (a iframe document script can read or write the parent document content but the latter cannot do the same). 
What happens when one url is of data: type? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Corner_cases_and_exceptions) is not so clear.

Comment: What are you referring to as "parent" and "child" documents? Iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Two documents (i.e. frames) from the same origin can equally change one another.

If there are such exceptions, it is probably a browser specific behavior or a bug.
Wikipedia term described some behaviors that are well known (e.g. loading script from a different domain), and might been by-design. You can also change the window.name (read-write) or location (write-only) from one frame to another, even when the origins are different.

I do not know the quirks wrt data URIs.

To recap: even if you will find some odd exception - don't expect it to work across multiple browsers + browser versions. Better work on a more solid solution to your problem.